# How to Overlay Text on Image Using HTML with no CSS?

Tags: html, content-management-system

I wanted to have a full-width call-to-action banner on my client's website. The template that my client has does not support CSS, so I'm making use of like old school HTML to build pages.

I have a background image for the img src and I want to overlay the text in it. I'm in need of a code that is working since I'm really not well-versed.

I searched up for solutions in adding overlay text to a background image, but most of the answers contain CSS. Here's a code that I tried.

```
<table>  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td rowspan=4><img src="/uploads/image12345jpg"></td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <center><td colspan=4>This is the overlay text</td></center>
  </tr>  
</table>
</center>
```

I'd appreciate your help and answers.

The support says that I have to individually add it in the HTML code... not sure where it goes.

Comment: Can someone explain to me how you can have an `.html` page that can't use CSS? Also, a template should not be able to not allow `css`, a framework maybe?  Am I missing something?

Comment: Would be interessting to see that page, because i don´t get it why your clients page won´t support CSS.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmithI I've tried the CSS codes and scripts in their end but it doesn't work. I asked support why does this keep happening then they told me that the template we have does not support CSS--this also confused me. So I've been building pages with just HTML only...

Comment: @d00dlesnitch then I think the only thing you can do is to chop up images and put them in a table, to give the look of a page?

Comment: Is this an x-y-problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/vz04m3ph/2/

```
<TABLE border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <TR> 
    <TD width="221" height="300" background="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" valign="bottom">
      <FONT size="+1" COLOR="red">This is the overlay text</FONT>
    </TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

EDIT:

This question is asking how to use inline styles, I think:

(I've also put some inline javascript on a click function because you mentioned your scripts wernt working either)
https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/vz04m3ph/28/

```
<td style="position:relative;">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" style="position:absolute;z-index:1;" width="600px" height="150px" />
  <div style="z-index:2;position:relative;color:red;font-weight:bold; font-size: 40px; top: 40px; left: 100px;" onClick="(function(){
    alert('See You can click me');
    return false;
});">
    <a href="#" onClick="(function(){ alert('See You can click me'); return false; })();return false;">
    your text goes here click here</a>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: unfortunately, no :( i appreciate your fiddle :) I was looking into something like this: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1366&bih=657&ei=EpQTXOHBHpKlwgONsb2gBg&q=banner+image&oq=business+powe&gs_l=img.1.0.0l10.7964.12242..14416...0.0..0.333.4036.2-3j10......2....1..gws-wiz-img.....0.RdmB-d6I9jg#imgrc=u3Ky-MG8KmXjUM:

I think I'll have to individually apply the CSS tags to the HTML one.

Comment: @d00dlesnitch you stated you cannot use `css` in your OP.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion, I'm also new to coding. It's like turning the CSS ```css``` into ```html```. Here was what I did when a time that I was looking for a button to use but CSS doesnt work.

```<div class="button" style="background-color: #f56b00"><a style="color:white" href="https://www.example.com">Example Button</a></div>``` I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @d00dlesnitch so you can use css? as long as it is inline? like this? https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/vz04m3ph/23/

Comment: @d00dlesnitch if you can use inline styles then you can pretty much do anything you want, you can also run scripts inline also.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: @d00dlesnitch check my edit in my answer, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Not really, but I've figured it out as we conversed here. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me. Thank you for the help! Appreciate it.

```
<div class="container" style="position:relative;text-align:center;color:white;" >
  <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="#" style="width:1880px;height:250px;" >
  <div class="centered" style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%, -50%);" >Example Text</div>
</div>
```